# How to collapse the values of a Series where the values are a list into a unique list

Tags: python, pandas, series

Given a Pandas Series like the one below:

```
0 [ID01]
1 [ID02]
2 [ID05, ID08]
3 [ID09, ID56, ID32]
4 [ID03]
```

The objective is to get a single list like the one below:

```
[ID01, ID02, ID05, ID08, ID09, ID56, ID32, ID03]
```

How do you achieve that in a pythonic way in Python?

Comment: Are you guaranteed to not have any duplicates? Or is removing duplicates part of the question here.

Comment: @miradulo good question. It would be nice to have both solutions: one that keeps the duplicates and what that does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that is a `pandas.Series` object

### Option 1

Full list

```
np.concatenate(s).tolist()
```

---

### Option 1.1

Unique list

```
np.unique(np.concatenate(s)).tolist()
```

---

### Option 2

Works if elements are lists.  Doesn't work if they are numpy arrays.
Full list

```
s.sum()
```

---

### Option 2.1

Unique list

```
pd.unique(s.sum()).tolist()
```

---

### Option 3

Full list

```
[x for y in s for x in y]
```

---

### Option 3.1

Unique list (Thanks @pault)

```
list({x for y in s for x in y})
```

---

### @Wen's Option

```
list(set.union(*map(set, s)))
```

---

### Setup

```
s = pd.Series([
    ['ID01'],
    ['ID02'],
    ['ID05', 'ID08'],
    ['ID09', 'ID56', 'ID32'],
    ['ID03']
])

s

0                [ID01]
1                [ID02]
2          [ID05, ID08]
3    [ID09, ID56, ID32]
4                [ID03]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I was going to post the same thing but I will add the comment that the title implies that OP wants unique values. In which case you can do a set comp instead of a list comp: `list({x for x in y for y in s})`.